# How to properly fill up SwapChain Struct to use Mulitsampling?

Tags: c++, struct, directx

Hi I just start with DirectX under CoreWindow^ + C++/CLI, all things seems to be ok until I want to start using a Mulitsampling.
This example is rendering the simple triangle

[Working example without AA](http://www28.zippyshare.com/v/IwZgGAnh/file.html)

When I fill the SwapChain struct like this:

```
UINT m4xMsaaQuality;


dev->CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,4, &m4xMsaaQuality);


// set up the swap chain description
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 scd = { 0 };

scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;    // how the swap chain should be used
scd.BufferCount =2;      

scd.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;              // the most common swap chain format
scd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;    // the recommended flip mode
scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                             // >1 enable anti-aliasing
scd.SampleDesc.Quality = m4xMsaaQuality-1;

CoreWindow^ Window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();    // get the window pointer

                                                           // create the swap chain
dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow(
    dev.Get(),                                  // address of the device
    reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(Window),        // address of the window
    &scd,                                       // address of the swap chain description
    nullptr,                                    // advanced
    &swapchain);                                // address of the new swap chain pointer



    // get a pointer directly to the back buffer
    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backbuffer;
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (&backbuffer));`
```

the

```
dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow(
dev.Get(),                                  // address of the device
reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(Window),        // address of the window
&scd,                                       // address of the swap chain description
nullptr,                                    // advanced
&swapchain);
```

return "nullptr",

I checked that m4xMsaaQuality is equal "17" so scd.SampleDesc.Quality =16

How I should fill up the SwapChain struct?

Answer (score 0):

Flip swap effects are not compatible with a multisampling surface. You need to create a non-msaa swap chain and explicitly resolve your msaa render to the swapchain buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, I read in MSDN about Multisampling in UWP app. But still I can't to render the smooth triangle. I changed the way of swapping - now should be correct for UWP application. I used also the ResolveSubresource

Can you take a look? The Window is complete black without a triangle. So far I finished with this code, Mostly I suspect the render target bacause when I uncomment this:

```
dev->CreateRenderTargetView(backbuffer.Get(), &renderTargetViewDesc, &rendertarget);
```

And in Render Method [line:210, 214] use "renderTarget"

```
[210] devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, rendertarget.GetAddressOf(), nullptr);

[214]devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(rendertarget.Get(), color);
```

Everything back to normal (of course without MSAA)

[Init_DirectX - render fail](http://www104.zippyshare.com/v/CMLa98vc/file.html)

Answer (score 0):

YES! Finally I menage to use this multisampling, I realize that
ResolveSubresource

> Copy a multisampled resource into a non-multisampled resource.

That why I don't have to recreating one more time the RenderViewTarget, just I can use my.

I still have question is there is some way to increase the anti-aliasing? The maximum sample what I can put in offScreenSurfaceDesc.SampleDesc.Count is 8.

[Init_DirectX with MSAA enable](http://www81.zippyshare.com/v/0T16X2ER/file.html)

Here is working solution.